# Group rows with sum and join (Build summary)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

There is a rowset like this:

```
| ID |     OP_CODE | OWNER |  MEASURE | COUNT |
|----|-------------|-------|----------|-------|
|  1 | Operation 1 |     1 | Geometry |    42 |
|  2 | Operation 1 |     1 | Geometry |    48 |
|  3 | Operation 1 |     1 |   Vacuum |    29 |
|  4 | Operation 1 |     1 |  Electro |    14 |
|  5 | Operation 1 |     2 | Geometry |    87 |
|  6 | Operation 1 |     2 | Geometry |   112 |
|  7 | Operation 1 |     2 |   Vacuum |    78 |
|  8 | Operation 1 |     3 |   Vacuum |    56 |
|  9 | Operation 1 |     3 |  Electro |    78 |
```

I want to group rows by **Owner** and merge/join other Measures (values of column MEASURE) with sum of column **Count** to this result like this:

```
| OWNER | GEOMETRY_CNT | VACUUM_CNT | ELECTRO_CNT | TOTAL_CNT |
|-------|--------------|------------|-------------|-----------|
|     1 |           90 |         29 |          14 |       133 |
|     2 |          199 |         78 |      (null) |       277 |
|     3 |       (null) |         56 |          78 |       134 |
```

In this case Geometry_cnt, Vacuum_cnt, Electro_cnt is a sum of corresponding values in first table:

Owner_1_Geometry_cnt=42+48=90;

Owner_1_Vacuum_cnt=29;

Owner_1_Electro_cnt=14;

Owner_1_TOTAL=29+14+90=133;

How can I get this rowset?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17f99/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.OWNER, SUM(IF(a.MEASURE = 'Geometry', a.COUNT, 0)) GEOMETRY_CNT, 
       SUM(IF(a.MEASURE = 'Vacuum', a.COUNT, 0)) VACUUM_CNT, 
       SUM(IF(a.MEASURE = 'Electro', a.COUNT, 0)) ELECTRO_CNT, 
       SUM(a.COUNT) TOTAL_CNT
FROM operations_schedule a 
GROUP BY a.OWNER
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8d74/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
| OWNER | GEOMETRY_CNT | VACUUM_CNT | ELECTRO_CNT | TOTAL_CNT |
|-------|--------------|------------|-------------|-----------|
|     1 |           90 |         29 |          14 |       133 |
|     2 |          199 |         78 |           0 |       277 |
|     3 |            0 |         56 |          78 |       134 |
```